# Unable to detect the kubelet URL automatically : datadog_checks.base.errors.CheckException

Tags: java, azure, docker, kubernetes, datadog

I set up datadog trace client in my kubernetes cluster to monitor my deployed application. It was working fine with the kubernetes version 1.15x but as soon as I upgraded the version to 1.16x, the service itself is not showing in the Datadog Dashboard.

Currently using:

1. Kubernetes 1.16.9
2. Datadog 0.52.0

When checked for agent status. It is giving following exception :

```
Instance ID: kubelet:xxxxxxxxxxxxx [ERROR]
      Configuration Source: file:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/kubelet.d/conf.yaml.default
      Total Runs: 12,453
      Metric Samples: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Events: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Service Checks: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Average Execution Time : 5ms
      Last Execution Date : 2020-06-19 15:18:19.000000 UTC
      Last Successful Execution Date : Never
      Error: Unable to detect the kubelet URL automatically.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py", line 822, in run
          self.check(instance)
        File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/kubelet/kubelet.py", line 297, in check
          raise CheckException("Unable to detect the kubelet URL automatically.")
      datadog_checks.base.errors.CheckException: Unable to detect the kubelet URL automatically.
```

This looks like a version issue to me. If it is which Datadog version I need to use for monitoring?

Comment: So Datadog dashboard is working but the service traces are not showing?

Comment: Exactly @PiotrMalec

Comment: This might be caused by changes introduced in `1.16`. Take a look at this blog [post](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/). I suggest trying to configure Datadog from scratrch.

Comment: This was not due to the Kubernetes version but with the Datadog version and its ways of fetching Kubelet. @PiotrMalec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a issue with deployed DataDog daemonset for me:

What I did to resolve:

1. Check daemonset if it exists or not:

   ```
   kubectl get ds -n datadog
   ```
2. Edit the datadog daemonset:

   ```
   kubectl edit ds datadog -n datadog
   ```
3. In the opened yaml, add

   ```
   - name: DD_KUBELET_TLS_VERIFY
     value: "false"
   ```

   Add this in **env:** tag for all places. For me there were 4 places which are having DD tags in the yaml.
4. Save and close it. The daemonset will restart. And the application will start getting traced.

Comment: Always there is a TLS issue with anything, people decide to just disable it :)

Comment: Is there any other solution you can suggest? As I was stuck in this and also a bit new to Datadog. @suren

Comment: thanks a lot! I was having a similar problem, and I applied this change and it was solved. Then I also added it in `datadog.env` for the Helm `values.yaml`, to install in any other cluster.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Helm chart, you can overwrite on the values:

```yaml
## https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/datadog/values.yaml

datadog:  
  # kubelet configuration
  kubelet:
    # datadog.kubelet.tlsVerify -- Toggle kubelet TLS verification
    # @default -- true
    tlsVerify:  false
```